# Fields in the table should have values equal to the length of the field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table, that has many columns with all kinds of datatypes. I want to fill these columns with values that will be of same length as the size of the field.

For example, if a table has a column called:

```
Test Varchar(255) NULL
```

Now this column can have values 'yes' or 'no'. But I want to fill this column to its max capacity, that is all 255 charachters. The value could be any random data. And I want to do this for all the columns in the table. Assume that all fields are varchar.

Comment: ur question is very unclear.. do u want a table with all varchar cols where each and every column should be filled completely with some random data?

Comment: I already have a table. Assume that it has all varchar columns. I just need to fill those columns to their max capacity.

Comment: I'm interested, why do you need to do this?

Comment: @beargle: I would guess they are a professional tester and want to find out if 'bad things happen' when valid but absurd data is entered ...or perhaps demonstrating to the coder that it is absurd to create a `Test Varchar(255)` column when all that is required is `Test CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'T' NOT NULL CHECK ( test IN ( 'T', 'F' ) )` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the column using `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`, SQL Server will always pad the field to the full width.

Alternatively you could use `LEN` and `REPLICATE` to pad the field manually with spaces (either left or right)

Another common trick is to pad with too many spaces and then truncate e.g.

```
SELECT RIGHT('      ...more than 255 spaces...           ' + myfield, 255)
SELECT LEFT(myfield + '      ...more than 255 spaces...           ', 255)
```

Take your pick.